# PySide: Creating a custom QCursor

Tags: python, pyside, custom-cursor

I'm trying to **setup a custom `QCursor` in PySide**, but there are no usable code samples on it.  As I understand, there's pixmap, and the pixmap's mask, which is set with `QPixmap.setMask()`.

I'm doing both:

```
    open_hand_px = QtGui.QPixmap('open_hand.png')
    open_hand_px.setMask(open_hand_px.mask())
    open_hand_cursor = QtGui.QCursor(pixmap=open_hand_px)
    self.setCursor(open_hand_cursor)
```

The image I'm using is loading fine, there are no errors, but the cursor refuses to change.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/):

> **About keyword arguments**
>
> Only optional arguments can be used as keyword arguments.

So, remove `pixmap=`:

```
open_hand_px = QtGui.QPixmap('open_hand.png')
open_hand_px.setMask(open_hand_px.mask())
open_hand_cursor = QtGui.QCursor(open_hand_px)
self.setCursor(open_hand_cursor)
```